# Hyperlink target location in the form of PHP variable is not working

Tags: php, hyperlink

My code is as follows

```
 <?
    $item_link = "http://www.rediff.com";

    //echo $item_link;
 ?>


   <li <?php learn_press_course_item_class( $item->ID ); ?> data-type="<?php echo $item->post_type; ?>">


       <a class="course-title" target="_self" href="<?=$item_link;?>">

           <?php echo $item_title; ?>

       </a>

   </li>
```

When clicked on the hyperlink it performs no action, tried putting link in various form but no use.

Comment: can you look at the html output and share that exactly? It might shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Resource requests whose URLs contain raw newline characters are deprecated.

**$item->post_type;** contains new line characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help..

The problem was with `<li>` tag just before `<a>` tag in the above code

```
<li <?php learn_press_course_item_class( $item->ID ); ?> data-type="<?php echo $item->post
```

I replaced this with

```
<li data-type="<?php echo $item->post
```

I think due to problem in this line it was not parsing url in the next line..